# Issue removing and readding series to chart

Tags: gwt, highcharts, jsni

I'm trying to write a method in GWT to override the series.show function for all Highcharts series, on show I want to essentially copy the series, remove the series from the chart, and readd it so that showing the series will redraw the line (instead of the default behavior where the line appears and the chart redraws). I have this modeled in a Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ax3o8uf3/16/

I used Moxie's highcharts wrapper for GWT and used the setSeriesPlotOptions() method to set the series show event handler and call this native method from inside the onShow().

```
public static native void showSeries(JavaScriptObject series, JavaScriptObject chart) /*-{
        var options = series.options;
        options.color = series.color;
        options.index = series.index;
        options.marker.symbol = series.symbol;

        series.remove();

        options.visible = true;
        chart.addSeries(options);
    }-*/;
```

and everything worked fine. Then we updated the project's highcharts and highstock.js files and it broke everything. Now hiding and showing a series in the legend will cause it to redraw fine for the first series you do it for, but as soon as you try and show another series it breaks and goes back to the default functionality for all series. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or what might be causing it to not work after showing a second series on the graph?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why but for some reason using the seriesShowEventHandler() caused it to break after trying to show more than one series, the solution I came up with was something like this:

```
setSeriesPlotOptions(new SeriesPlotOptions().setSeriesLegendItemClickEventHandler(new SeriesLegendItemClickEventHandler() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClick(SeriesLegendItemClickEvent seriesLegendItemClickEvent) {

            Series series = getSeries(seriesLegendItemClickEvent.getSeriesId());

            if(seriesLegendItemClickEvent.isVisible()) {
                series.hide();
            } else if((series.getOptions().get("type").toString()).equals("\"line\"")){
                removeAndReAddSeries(getNativeChart(), series.getNativeSeries());
            } else {
                series.show();
            }
            return false;
        }

    }));
```